# Olympiad problem with complete quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, contest-math

This problem appeared at the Croatian Mathematical Olympiad (HMO) in 2021 as part of a selection test for the team for the Middle European Mathematical Olympiad. The problem reads as follows (I've tried my best to translate it):

Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral whose diagonals intersect at point $E$. Lines $AB$ and $CD$ intersect at point $P$, and lines $AD$ and $BC$ intersect at point $Q$. Let $X$ be the intersection of $(EBC)$ and $(EDA)$, with $X\ne E$, and let $Y$ be the intersection of $(EAB)$ and $(ECD)$, with $Y\ne E$. Finally, let $W$ be the intersection of $(PBC)$ and $(PDA)$, with $W\ne P$. Prove that triangles $WQY$ and $WXP$ are similar.

[image: My attempt at the sketch]

What I've tried so far is proving $\triangle WBY \sim \triangle WXD$ as well as $\triangle WBQ \sim \triangle WPD$ so that $$\angle QWY = \angle QWB - \angle YWB = \angle DWP - \angle DWX = \angle XWP$$ and $$\frac{WQ}{WY}=\frac{WQ}{WB}\cdot\frac{WB}{WY}=\frac{WD}{WP}\cdot\frac{WX}{WD}=\frac{WX}{WP}$$
But I can't seem to prove the first two similarities. I've tried applying spiral similarity and Miquel's quadrilateral theorem but I wasn't able to complete the proof. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\triangle WBQ \sim \triangle WPD$ follows from the fact that $W$ is the center of the spiral similarity taking $\overline{BQ}$ into $\overline{PD}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the plane is the plane of complex numbers. The complex number that represents $A$ will be the lowercase $a$. Similarly we have $b,c,d,p,q,w,x,y$. WLOG assume $a=0$ and $b=1$.

Since $W$ is the center of the spiral similarity for $AD$ and $BC$,
$$w={\frac {ac-db}{a+c-d-b}}=\frac{-d}{c-d-1}.$$

Since $X$ is the center of the spiral similarity for $AC$ and $DB$,
$$x={\frac {ab-cd}{a+b-c-d}}=\frac{-cd}{1-c-d}.$$

Since $Y$ is the center of the spiral similarity for $AB$ and $CD$,
$$y={\frac {ad-bc}{a+d-b-c}}=\frac{-c}{d-1-c}.$$

$$p=\frac{\Im(\overline{b}a)(d-c)-\Im(\overline{d}c)(b-a)}{\Im(\overline{b-a}(d-c))}=\frac{-\Im(\overline dc)}{\Im(d-c)}.$$
$$q=\frac{\Im(\overline{d}a)(b-c)-\Im(\overline{b}c)(d-a)}{\Im(\overline{d-a}(b-c))}=\frac{-\Im(c)d}{\Im(\overline{d}(1-c))}.$$

$w-p=\frac{-d\,\Im(d-c)+\Im(\overline dc)(c-d-1)}{(c-d-1)\,\Im(d-c)}=\frac{\Im(\overline{d}(1-c))(d-c)}{(c-d-1)\,\Im(d-c)}.$
$w-q=\frac{-d\,\Im(\overline d(1-c))+\Im(c)d(c-d-1)}{(c-d-1)\,\Im(\overline{d}(1-c))}=\frac{\Im(d-c)d(1-c)}{(c-d-1)\,\Im(\overline{d}(1-c))}.$
$w-x=\frac{-d(1-c-d)+cd(c-d-1)}{(c-d-1)(1-c-d)}=\frac{d(d-c-1)(1-c)}{(c-d-1)(1-c-d)}.$
$w-y=\frac{-d(d-1-c)+c(c-d-1)}{(c-d-1)(d-c-1)}=\frac{(d-c)(1-c-d)}{(c-d-1)(d-c-1)}.$
$(w-p)(w-q)=\frac{d(1-c)(d-c)}{(c-d-1)^2}=(w-x)(w-y).$
Hence $\triangle WQY \sim \triangle WXP$.

Comment: It is straightforward to verify  $(w-b)(w-d)=(w-x)(w-y)$.  Hence $\triangle WBQ \sim \triangle WPD$, as suspected by OP.

Comment: Do you mean $\triangle WBY \sim \triangle WXD$?

Comment: Yes, of course. Thanks.

Comment: $(w-a)(w-c)=(w-b)(w-d)=(w-p)(w-q)=(w-x)(w-y)$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Hint: Use these figures , start from simple form shown in second figure, where quadrilateral is a kite. The key point is that in all cases $WE\bot AC$. If you rotate triangle WQY about vertex W such that WQ coincides on WX you get triangle WQ'Y' and you can see that WQ' coincides on WP and $Q'Y'||PX$. Hope this helps.

Comment: But $WE$ is generally not perpendicular to $AC$

Comment: so many circles!!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Synthetic solution:
It's enough to prove $\triangle WBY \sim \triangle WXD$ and $\triangle WBQ \sim \triangle WPD$.

$W$ is the Miquel point of quadrilateral $ABCD$, so it's the center of the spiral similarity sending $\overline{BQ}$ to $\overline{PD}$, therefore $\triangle WBQ \sim \triangle WPD$.

Now let $K$, $L$, $M$, $N$ be the midpoints of $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{BC}$, $\overline{CD}$, $\overline{DA}$ respectively. $X$ is the center of the spiral similarity sending $\overline{AC}$ to $\overline{DB}$, so $\triangle XAC \sim \triangle XDB$. It follows that
$$\frac{LM}{LK}=\frac{BD}{CA}=\frac{XD}{XA}$$ and $$\angle MLK = 180 ^{\circ}-\angle CLM - \angle KLB = 180 ^{\circ} - \angle CBD - \angle ACB = \angle DEA = \angle DXA$$
therefore $\triangle LMK \sim \triangle XDA$.

Furthermore, $W$ is the center of the spiral similarity sending $\overline{AB}$ to $\overline{DC}$, so it takes $K$ to $M$. Since it's the center of the spiral similarity that sends $\overline{AK}$ to $\overline{DM}$, it's also the center of the spiral similarity that sends $\overline{AD}$ to $\overline{KM}$, but since $\triangle LMK \sim \triangle XDA$, this spiral similarity sends $\overline{LM}$ to $\overline{XD}$, so $\triangle WLM \sim \triangle WXD$. Analogously, $\triangle WLM \sim \triangle WBY$, so $\triangle WBY \sim \triangle WXD$.