# Another olympiad problem with a complete quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, contest-math, quadrilateral

*Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral whose diagonals intersect at $P$. Let $X$ and $Y$ be points such that quadrilaterals $ABPX$, $CDXP$, $BCPY$, and $DAYP$ are cyclic. Lines $AB$ and $CD$ intersect at $Q$, $BC$ and $DA$ intersect at $R$, $XR$ and $YQ$ intersect at Z. Prove that $X$, $Y$, $Z$, $P$ are concyclic.*

[image]

This problem appeared on the Croatian IMO TST in 2021. It's very similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4704363/olympiad-problem-with-complete-quadrilateral) problem that appeared on the MEMO TST in the same year. I'm stuck. I'm guessing the solution involves spiral similarities and properties of Miquel points, but I can't seem to make any progress. Again, any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let RXZ cut the circles ABPX and CDXP at S and T respectively.

[image]

Join CT. By “properties of cyclic quad.”, $\angle 1 = \angle 2 = \angle 3$. This means SA // CT. Then, $\alpha = \beta$.

Extend SA to cut the circle ADPY at U. After joining DU, we have $\beta = \gamma$.

$\alpha = \gamma$ implies TDU is a straight line.

Through the similar logic, (I think) we should get the result of VCT and VBS are all straight lines.

Required result follows because $\angle red = \angle pink$ and $\angle pink = \angle orange$.

Comment: After some reflection I've realized that this is not enough. Similar reasoning doesn't get us far after this, but I think we're on the right track. We haven't used $Q$ and $R$ yet.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is very similar to the solution to the linked problem.

[image: diagram]

Let $K$, $L$, $M$, $N$, $E$, $F$ be the midpoints of segments $AB$, $CD$, $AD$, $CB$, $AC$, $BD$ respectively. Let $W$ be the other intersection of the circumcircles of triangles $RAB$ and $QAD$. $W$ also lies on the circumcircles of triangles $RCD$ i $QCB$. Similarly, $X$ lies on the circumcircles of triangles $QAC$ and $QBD$ as well, and $Y$ also lies on the circumcircles of triangles $RAC$ and $RBD$.

$W$ is the center of the spiral similarity taking $A$ to $B$ and $D$ to $C$, so $\triangle WAD\sim\triangle WBC$. We have
$$\frac{KE}{KF}=\frac{BC}{AD}=\frac{WC}{WD}$$
and $\sphericalangle(EK, KF)=\sphericalangle(EK, KA) + \sphericalangle(BK, KF)=\sphericalangle(CB, BA) + \sphericalangle(BA, AD)=\sphericalangle(CR, RD)=\sphericalangle(CW, WD)$,
so $\triangle KEF\sim\triangle WCD$. $X$ is the center of the spiral similarity taking $A$ to $B$ and $C$ to $D$, so that spiral similarity takes $E$ to $F$. It follows that $X$ is also the center of the spiral similarity taking $E$ to $C$ and $F$ to $D$, therefore $\triangle XEF\sim\triangle XCD$. We have
$$\frac{EX}{EK}=\frac{EX}{EF}\cdot \frac{EF}{EK}=\frac{CX}{CD}\cdot \frac{CD}{CW}=\frac{CX}{CW}$$
and $\sphericalangle(XE, EK) = \sphericalangle(XE, EF) + \sphericalangle(FE, EK) = \sphericalangle(XC, CD) + \sphericalangle(DC, CW) = \sphericalangle(XC, CW)$,
hence $\triangle XKE\sim\triangle XWC$.

By similar reasoning, $\triangle XKE\sim\triangle XBY$, therefore $\triangle XWC\sim\triangle XBY$. $X$ is the center of the spiral similarity taking $C$ to $Q$ and $P$ to $B$, so $\triangle XCP\sim\triangle XQB$. Now we have
$$\frac{XW}{XP} = \frac{XW}{XC}\cdot \frac{XC}{XP} = \frac{XB}{XY}\cdot\frac{XQ}{XB} = \frac{XQ}{XY}$$
and $\sphericalangle(WX, XP) = \sphericalangle(WX, XC) + \sphericalangle(CX, XP) = \sphericalangle(BX, XY) + \sphericalangle(QX, XB) = \sphericalangle(QX, XY)$,
therefore $\triangle XWP\sim\triangle XQY$. Similarly, $\triangle YWP\sim\triangle YRX$. Finally,
$\sphericalangle(XP, PY) = \sphericalangle(XP, PW) + \sphericalangle(WP, PY) = \sphericalangle(XY, YQ) + \sphericalangle(RX, XY) = \sphericalangle(XZ, ZY)$,
Hence $X$, $Y$, $Z$, $P$ are concyclic.

$\blacksquare$

---

A nice result that follows from this is that $E$ and $F$ (as defined above) also lie on $(XYZP)$. Also, as was noticed by Mick in his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4828648/933355), if we let $S$ and $T$ be the second intersections of $XR$ with $(PAB)$ and $(PCD)$ respectively, and we let $U$ and $V$ be the second intersections of $YQ$ with $(PAD)$ and $(PCB)$ respectively, then $SVTU$ is a parallelogram whose sides contain points $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$. Furthermore, $SVTU$ is similar to the parallelogram $MLNK$.